# Incomparable object types --> Object to string?

Tags: java, string, object

The method I have is supposed to return a String [] so i used toArray method. But I get error regarding object cannot be converted to strings. I have initialized the list as String as well and am unable to figure out the error that I am getting. Everywhere I read, they say initialize as String and I have already done that. how can I fix it??

```
 ArrayList<String> c = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(a));
.......(job done)
return c.toArray();
```

--The entire code:

```
public static String[] anagrams(String [] a) {
        ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(a));
        ArrayList<String> c = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(a));
        int l=a.length;
        int i,j;
        for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
            for (j=i+1;j<l;j++) {
                if (check(b.get(i),b.get(j))){
                    if (c.contains(b.get(j)))
                        c.remove(j);
                }    
            }
        }
        return c.toArray();
}
```

Comment: It will be better to provide the code of the function you're written.

Comment: i have posted the code!!

Answer (score 1):

Tryy this

```
 return c.toArray(new String[c.size()]);
```

This basically initializes size of the array

Answer (score 1):

There are two `toArray` methods in an `ArrayList`. From the *docs*:

```
Object[] toArray()
Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper sequence (from first to last element).

<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper sequence (from first to last element); the runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array.
```

Right now you are using the first version, which returns an `Object` array. Since you want a `String` array, not an `Object` array, you must use the second version:

```
return c.toArray(new String[0]);
```

The array parameter is needed so `ArrayList` knows which type to return. If you provide an empty array, `ArrayList` will allocate a new array for the desired type. However you can also provide an array that is big enough for all elements of the list, then `ArrayList` will use that array instead of initializing a new one:

```
return c.toArray(new String[c.size()]);
```